# Insert overwrite in Hive

Tags: hive

I am trying to use Insert overwrite in Hive. Basically I would like to insert overwrite not the complete partition but only a few records in the partition. I am not finding any solution to do it (Insert overwrite in destination table based on a filter on non partition column also). 
Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: You want to update only specific rows?

Answer (score 1):

Hive is not as Regular RDBMS, If you want to update the record simple do INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE Table_Name...simple change your data in one temporary table or by using WITH clause simply insert overwrite..by using table partioning..it  is safe.

QUERY[HIVE]:

WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_TABLE_NAME) INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TARGET_TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE

Answer (score 1):

Hive is not an RDBMS. What you are trying to achieve with Hive is not recommended. Hive is better suited for batch processing over very large sets of immutable data.

However, from what I could deduce, you are trying to update an existing record in your table. To do so, enable ACID support on the table that needs to be updated and your update queries will start working.

```
UPDATE <TABLE>
SET <COL1>='Value1',
SET <COL2>='Value2'
WHERE <Some Condition That Only Evaluates To The Rows You Need Updated>
```